# How to enable links if a parent element uses a fullscreen pseudo-element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

My page looks like this:

```
<div.ui-page>
  <div.ui-content>
    <a href="foo.html">
  </div>
</div>
```

On my page, I'm setting a fullscreen watermark like so:

```css
/* Watermark */
.ui-page:before {
    background: url("../img/foo.png") no-repeat center center;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* transparency */
    opacity: .2;
    /* grayscale */
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(10%) contrast(100%);
}
```

Which works fine. Problem is, my link is no longer clickable.

I tried moving around the `:before` pseudo element along with various degrees of z-index. All don't work. Strangely though this only seems to pertain to basic links. Any links wrapped in other elements work fine (I'm using jQuery Mobile, so links say inside a `ul` work)

**Question**:
How can I keep a plain link clickable/workable if a parent element or the element that contains the link uses a CSS pseudo element?

Thanks!

**Solution**:
Here is my final code. **Note**, I had to switch to `ui-page-active` - otherwise it only works on the first page being loaded in jQuery Mobile.

```css
.ui-page-active:before {
    background: url("../img/foo.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* transparency */
    opacity: .2;
    /* grayscale */
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(10%) contrast(100%);
}
/* disable pointer events on the background... */
.ui-page.ui-page-active:before {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is not 100% cross-browser, but you can add the following code to make the mouse click-through the element:

```
.ui-page:before {
  pointer-events:auto;
}
```

Read Lea Verou's excellent [CSS secrets](http://lea.verou.me/css3-secrets/#slide16) guide for more info

EDIT:

If that fails, try adding:

```
.ui-page { pointer-events: none; }
.ui-page:before { pointer-events: none; }
```

I tested this out in my own app. Hope it helps.

Comment: Good idea. Let me try.

Comment: Cool. Works now. I only use the second line, because I need `pointer-events` on my page element, but not on the `:before`, because that just contains the background. Thanks a lot. Much better than setting position,

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `position: relative;` on your .ui-content div.

z-index only works on positioned elements, so when you position your div, it will calculate the z-index and your link will be clickable.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uBuSE/

Comment: any idea how to give elements "position" without specifically declaring `pos:relative`?

Comment: Only way you can give them position that enables z-index is pos: relative, absolute or fixed.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Sorry. Other answer is perfect now.